# Ruby koans - error with obj.object_id.class

Tags: ruby

I'm going through Ruby Koans, and I"m getting hung up on the test_every_object_has_an_id method in about_objects.rb. The supplied code reads like so:

```
def test_every_object_has_an_id
   obj = Object.new
   assert_equal __, obj.object_id.class
end
```

I know that the answer is Fixnum, but, whenever I run path_to_enlightenment.rb, I get the following error message:

```
custom_require.rb:36:in `require':about_objects.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) from rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from path_to_enlightenment.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Is there some sort of bug in the code as supplied, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could be a bug, did you make sure you worked on a clean install of the koans?

Answer (score 1):

### Missing `end` Keyword

Somewhere else in your files you have a missing `end` keyword. Some file is reaching the end of the source file before finding the expected keyword. The error clearly tells you so:

```
custom_require.rb:36:in `require':about_objects.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) from rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require' from path_to_enlightenment.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Check lines 7, 36, and 50 of the named files. That's the problem you need to fix, and has nothing to do with the fact that:

```
Object.new.object_id.class
#=> Fixnum
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't ask you which class it is, it ask what Fixnum class is. So the answer must be **Object**

```
>> Object.new.object_id.class.is_a? Fixnum
#=> false
>> Object.new.object_id.class.is_a? Object
#=> true
```

Comment: Object doesn't work, either. Plus, when I run 'puts Object.new.object_id.class', it returns Fixnum. I'm not really sure is_a?(Fixnum) returns false, when 'puts class' returns Fixnum.

Comment: Why not sure? If you create an instance from Fixnum class, it "is a" Fixnum, but class's itself is an Object. try this:

    >> 12.is_a? Fixnum  #=> true

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. object_id.class is Fixnum, but object_id.class.is_a? is asking about the class of Fixnum, which is object. Is that correct?

Comment: It's asking about the `object_id`'s class ( `Fixnum`), not about `object_id`'s classes' class.  Try it.

Comment: All you have to do is run the code that is in the question to see that it's expecting `Fixnum`: `Object.new.object_id.class => Fixnum`. Why do you persist in arguing that it's expecting `Object`???